# Using sage dll's within .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sage-erp

I have a console application with .NET Core and need to use the dll's from Sage which depends on .NET framework. I need following:

[image]

Actually it can compile and run through, but then I get following error while creation a session and mandant:

*Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

I already tried to add mscorlib via add reference in VS, but didn't work.

Any ideas? I really don't want to go back to .NET framework with my projct just to use the sage dll's ;-)

Comment: Looks like you need to target your project for Net Version 4.0.

Comment: It works  for .NET 4.72, but I need it work .NET Core...

Comment: You need to recompile Sage with Net Core.  Which version of core are you using 2.0 or 3.0?  Not all the functions in Net 4.72 are implemented in Core so you may need to do some redesign or upgrade to Core 3.0.

Comment: I use .NET Core 3.0. How can I recompile Sage with .NET Core?

Comment: Are you getting errors?  Not all Net classes are in Core so you may need to make modfications.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that these sage DLLs are compatible with core? What does the vendor say?